# Work done in thermodynamic process

Tags: thermodynamics

[image: Source Jee Main 2020]

Here the official answer key given by Jee main is 48 Joules which makes no sense I believe that they just blindly found the area under the curve . if I am correct the answer should be 48+2*10(the area of rectangle below the (2,2) point ) as work done area under the PV graph with volume axis
please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If an authority said 3x4=15, would you call for checking your analysis that  3x4=12? I guess you would not as you would see they were wrong. This case is very similar. Why did you not see they were wrong here?

Comment: haha ik but even many teachers gave the wrong soln uk so i had to confirm and yeh jee is an all india level exam in which  usually they change the answer key if they commit any mistake

Comment: It is good if they at least acknowledge errors. But considering the particular values, the whole task is made up for the sake of the task, far from real problems.

Comment: Generally, you should not ask if your result is correct, but you should verify your calculation procedure and eventually ask about its details where you are unsure. You either know how to do it either you do not.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like they have set the trap of shifted axis, but they have fallen for it themselves.

$$W=\int_{V_1}^{V_2}{p \cdot \mathrm{d}V},$$

so $$W=(\pu{8 m3}- \pu{2 m3}) \cdot \pu{8 Pa} + (\pu{12 m3} - \pu{8 m3}) \cdot \frac{\pu{8 Pa} + \pu{2 Pa}}{2}  = \pu{48 J} + \pu{20 J} = \pu{68 J}$$